# Determining whether a VMWare VM is an SRM placeholder

Tags: ansible, vmware

When searching for VMWare VMs by name, we get duplicate results because we have "placeholder" VMs created by the Site Recovery Manager.  With the Ansible modules, I have been unable to distinguish the "real" VM from the SRM placeholder VM.  With PowerCLI, one can look at `ExtensionData.Config.ManagedBy.ExtensionKey` https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/PowerCLI-How-to-distinguish-real-vm-from-SRM-placeholder/m-p/2214006, but I do not see how to do that with Ansible.

Comment: Can you give us some context and ideally some example code that you have tried - I don't really know what you are asking here. Are you trying to write a dynamic inventory script? Are you trying to search an existing inventory? Are you firing some task that depends on querying VMWare, perhaps via the `uri` module?

Comment: I've just used `vmwage_vm_info` and `vmware_guest_info`, and cannot find anything in the returned JSON that indicates that the VM is an SRM placeholder.